# How to Add Data Labels to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Attempting to add data labels to a barplot, using ggplot is giving me the following error:

```
Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x
```

My sample data is as below:

```
| Team          | Goals     |
|------------   |-------    |
| Manchester    | 26        |
| Liverpool     | 25        |
| Man City      | 30        |
| Chelsea       | 32        |
| Arsenal       | 11        |
| West Ham      | 22        |
| Stoke         | 23        |
```

And here is the code I am using to create a barplot.

```
g<- ggplot(data = scores) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=Team, y=Goals, color = Team, fill = Team), 
           stat = "identity")
g <- g + ggtitle("Goals per Team") + ylab("Number of Goals")
g <- g + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
g + geom_text(aes(y=Goals, label=Goals))
g
```

Even when I add `x = Team` in `g + geom_text(aes(x = Team, y=Goals, label=Goals))`, it still gives me the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You've put `x=Team` inside `geom_bar`, so `geom_text` doesn't know about it. If you want an aesthetic to apply to all geoms, put it in the main call to `ggplot`. For example, in your case, do `ggplot(data = scores, aes(x=Team, y=Goals))` and then you won't need to mention these mappings again in `geom_bar` or `geom_text`. If you want the text labels to also be mapped to color, then include `colour=Team` inside the main call to `ggplot` as well.

Answer (score 13):

Putting all together from the comment and adding reodering of teams by number of goals, the code below

```
# add on: reorder teams by number of goals
scores$Team <- with(scores, reorder(Team, -Goals))
g <- ggplot(scores, 
            # keep all aesthetics in one place
            aes(x = Team, y = Goals, color = Team, fill = Team, label = Goals)) +
  # replacement of geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_col() +
  # avoid overlap of text and bar to make text visible as bar and text have the same colour 
  geom_text(nudge_y = 1) + 
  # alternatively, print text inside of bar in discriminable colour
  # geom_text(nudge_y = -1, color = "black") + 
  ggtitle("Goals per Team") + 
  xlab("Team") + ylab("Number of Goals") +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
g
```

creates this chart:

[image]

## Data

```
scores <- structure(list(Team = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("Chelsea", 
"Man City", "Manchester", "Liverpool", "Stoke", "West Ham", "Arsenal"
), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(-11, -32, -25, -30, 
-26, -23, -22), .Dim = 7L, .Dimnames = list(c("Arsenal", "Chelsea", 
"Liverpool", "Man City", "Manchester", "Stoke", "West Ham")))), 
    Goals = c(26L, 25L, 30L, 32L, 11L, 22L, 23L)), .Names = c("Team", 
"Goals"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```